# FREE3OF9 barcode font not displaying in Firefox's new built-in PDF viewer

Tags: firefox, pdf, fpdf

I have a PHP web app that uses FPDF (v1.53) and the FREE3OF9 barcode font to dynamically generate a PDF which includes a barcode string in it.  In versions of Firefox prior to 19, the PDF opened in a new tab, was displayed by the Adobe Acrobat plugin, and the barcode showed up perfectly fine.

Now that Firefox 19.0 is using its own built-in PDF viewer, the barcode no longer displays at all.  It continues to display fine in IE and Chrome.  How I can get the barcode to display correctly in the newest version of Firefox?

Comment: Are you embedding the font in the PDF? If not, I wonder if it will render on some viewers and not others if it isn't a common font (depending on whether it is 'built in' to the editor and/or if it uses the fonts available on the system it runs on).

Comment: It's always rendered fine on every viewer we've tried it on, except now in the new Firefox viewer.

Comment: I also experienced troubles with that built in pdf viewer. When I try to output generated by fpdf file in browser, javaScript error occurs. If you just need to see that barcode on your machine, you can change in tools->options->applications->portable document format (pdf) and set your previous choice. But if you want to make it display correct for all users - I also can't find solution so far.